# Excel: Dropdowns and IF feature

Tags: excel

I have a cell with a dropdown menu of 20 items in a list. Upon clicking one of these 20 items, I want the next cell to produce another drop down with a list of options. The list in this dropdown will differ depending on what choice is taken from the first drop down. Following this, I want the chosen option in the second dropdown to output a number in another cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to start by creating `Named Lists` of dependent list, and use `INDIRECT` function in `Data Validataion -> List` to achieve dependent drop down list or cascading drop down list.

Its explained in detail with screen shots [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/)!

Refer this [link](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) if you are using older Excel version.